# Pandas functions in custom class from another module

Tags: python, pandas, class, import, module

I have two modules, main and helpers. I want to build a function collection. Firstly I want to do EDA processes at once. But the function in below doesn't print head, tail or sample rows.

Result of the codes:

```
Rows: 1460
Columns: 81
 - - - - - 
HEAD
 - - - - - 
TAIL
 - - - - - 
SAMPLES
 - - - - -
```

main.py

```
import pandas as pd
from ModuleWizard.helpers import HelperFunctions
train = pd.read_csv(PATH)
helper = HelperFunctions()
helper.EDA(train)
```

helper.py

```
class HelperFunctions():
    def EDA(self, dataframe):
        print(f"Rows: {dataframe.shape[0]}")
        print(f"Columns: {dataframe.shape[1]}")
        print(" - - - - - ")

        print("HEAD")
        print(dataframe.head())
        print(" - - - - - ")
        print("TAIL")
        print(dataframe.tail())
        print(" - - - - - ")
        print("SAMPLES")
        print(dataframe.sample(5))
```

**It works only in the same module.**

helpers.py

```
class HelperFunctions():
    def EDA(self, dataframe):
        ...

import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_csv(PATH)
HelperFunctions().EDA(train)
```